# Check Auto-renewable InApp Purchase iOS

Tags: ios8, in-app-purchase, payment, auto-renewing, skpaymenttransaction

I am implementing Auto-renewable InApp Purchase for iOS. It is working fine for first month. But I am unable to know whether user's subscription is auto renewed or not means what is the status of current InApp Purchase.

After studying so many answers on StackOverflow, I am able to understand that I have to provide Restore button to Restore transaction. I have implemented it as well and it is giving my all transactions till date. So, I am unable to get my last transaction. So, please help to understand the status of last auto renewed transaction so that I shall be able to update the status on my server.

Below is the code I am using to restore my transaction:

```
 [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue]restoreCompletedTransactions];
```

and implementing its delegates as follows:

```
- (void)paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue {
NSLog(@"%@",queue );
NSLog(@"Restored Transactions are once again in Queue for purchasing %@",[queue transactions]);

NSMutableArray *purchasedItemIDs = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSLog(@"received restored transactions: %zd", queue.transactions.count);

for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in queue.transactions)
{
    NSString *productID = transaction.payment.productIdentifier;
    [purchasedItemIDs addObject:productID];
    NSLog (@"product id is %@" , productID.description);
    NSLog (@"observationInfo is %@" , transaction.payment.productIdentifier.observationInfo);


    // here put an if/then statement to write files based on previously purchased items
    // example if ([productID isEqualToString: @"youruniqueproductidentifier]){write files} else { nslog sorry}
}
 }


- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue restoreCompletedTransactionsFailedWithError:(NSError *)error
  {
    NSLog(@"Restore Error... %@",error.description);
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess transaction restore is not work if application is running and Transaction is renew. Please refer StoreKit Guide :-

> After a subscription is successfully renewed, Store Kit adds a
>   transaction for the renewal to the transaction queue. Your app checks
>   the transaction queue on launch and handles the renewal the same way
>   as any other transaction. Note that if your app is already running
>   when the subscription renews, the transaction observer is not called;
>   your app finds out about the renewal the next time it’s launched.

After relaunch application, Transaction restore functionality work fine with restoring current auto-renewed transaction.

On Alternate, If you want to check transaction is renewed or not without relaunch application, You can do with manually refreshing **"App Receipt"**.

Link (Expiration and Renewal) :- https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/Subscriptions.html